# Get system calls IDs and store them in a .txt file(LINUX)

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system, monitors

So i've been struggling with this exercise. I must get al of the System Calls made by any given Linux command of my choice (I.E. ls or cd), list them in a .txt file, and have their unique IDs listed beside them.

So far here's what i got:

```
strace -o filename.txt ls
```

This when executed in the Linux shell gives me a "filename.txt" file containing all the system calls of the ls command. Now in my C script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
     system("strace -o filename.txt ls");
     return 0;
}
```

This should do the same as the previous code, but it's not returning me anything, although the code succesfully compiles. How would i go about fixing this, and then get the IDs? I'm using the "stdlib" library because in my research i found that it has some relation to system call IDs, but haven't found any indication on how to get them. Basically i must read that file i created and have it give each system call its ID.

Comment: what's the point of executing the shell command from your own program? If you were asked to do that in c, you should probably have a look at [man ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)

Comment: 1) C is not a scripting language. 2) @FelixPalmen is right: it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The exercise is obviously designed to be solved by using the [`ptrace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) facility, because the [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) utility does not have an option to print the syscall number (as far as I know).

Technically, you can use something like

```
printf '#include <sys/syscall.h>\n' | gcc -dD -E - | awk '$1 == "#define" { m[$2] = $3 } END { for (name in m) if (name ~ /^SYS_/) { v = name; while (v in m) v = m[v]; sub(/^SYS_/, "", name); printf "%s %s\n", v, name } }'
```

to generate a number of `syscall-number syscall-name` lines, to be used for mapping syscall names back to syscall numbers, but this would be silly and error-prone. Silly, because being able to use `ptrace()` gives you much more control than using the `strace` utility, and using a "clever hack" like above just means you avoid learning how to do that, which in my opinion is by definition self-defeating and therefore utterly silly; and error-prone, because there is absolutely no guarantee that the installed headers match the running architecture. This is especially problematic on multiarch architectures, where you can use `-m32` and `-m64` compiler options to switch between 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. They typically have completely different syscall numbers.

Essentially, your program should:

1. `fork()` a child process.

   In the child process:

   1. Enable ptracing by calling [`prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1L)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html)
   2. Make parent process the tracer by calling [`ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, (pid_t)0, (void *)0, (void *)0)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)
   3. Optionally, set tracing options. For example, call `ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, getpid(), PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE | PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC | PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK)` so that you catch at least `clone()`, `fork()`, and exec() family of syscalls.

      If you do not set the `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` option, you should stop the child process at this point using e.g. `raise(SIGSTOP);`, so that the parent process can start tracing this child.
   4. Execute the command to be traced using e.g. [`execv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html). In particular, if the first command line parameter is the command to run, optionally followed by its options, you can use `execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);`.

      If you set the `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` option above, then the kernel will auto-pause the child process just before executing the new binary.

      If the exec fails, the child process should exit.  I like to use `exit(127);`, to return exit status 127.
2. In the parent process, use [`waitpid(childpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) in a loop, to catch events in the child process.

   The very first event should be the initial pause, i.e. `WIFSTOPPED(status)` being true. (If not, something else went wrong.)
3. There are three three different reasons why `waitpid(childpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED)` may return:

   - When the child exits (`WIFEXITED(status)` will be true).
     This should obviously end the tracing, and have the parent tracer process exit, too.
   - When the child resumes execution (`WIFCONTINUED(status)` will be true).

     You cannot assume that a `PTRACE_SYSCALL`, `PTRACE_SYSEMU`, `PTRACE_CONT` etc. commands have actually caused the child process to continue, until the parent gets this signal.  In other words, you cannot just fire `ptrace()` commands to the child process, and expect them to take place in an orderly fashion! The `ptrace()` facility is asynchronous, and the call will return immediately; you need to `waitpid()` for the `WIFCONTINUED(status)` type of event to know that the child process heeded the command.
   - When the kernel stopped the child (with `SIGTRAP`) because the child process is about to execute a syscall. (In the parent, `WIFSTOPPED(status)` will be true.)
4. Whenever the child process gets stopped because it is about to execute a syscall, you need to use `ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, childpid, (void *)0, &regs)` to obtain the CPU register state in the child process at the point of syscall execution.

   `regs` is of type `struct user`, defined in `<sys/user.h>`. For Intel/AMD architectures, `regs.regs.eax` (for 32-bit) or `regs.regs.rax` (for 64-bit) contains the syscall number (`SYS_foo` as defined in `<sys/syscall.h>`.

   You then need to call `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, childpid, (void *)0, (void *)0)` to tell the kernel to execute that syscall, and `waitpid()` again to wait for the `WIFCONTINUED(status)` event notifying that it did.

   The next `WIFSTOPPED(status)` type event from `waitpid()` will occur when the syscall is completed. If you want, you can use `PTRACE_GETREGS` again to examine `regs.regs.eax` or `regs.regs.rax`, which contains the syscall return value; on Intel/AMD, if an error occurred, it will be a negative errno value (i.e. `-EACCES`, `-EINVAL`, or similar.)

   You need to call `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, childpid, (void *)0, (void *)0)` to tell the kernel to continue running the child, until the next syscall.

There are quite a few examples on-line showing some of the details above, although most that I have personally seen are pretty lax on error checking, and occasionally omit checking the `WIFCONTINUED(status)` `waitpid()` events. I've even written an answer detailing how to stop and continue individual threads on StackOverflow. Since the technique can be used as a very powerful custom debugging tool, I do recommend you try to learn the facility so you can leverage it in your work, rather than just copy-paste some existing code to get a passing grade on the exercise.